# duplicate PUT request in AngularJs with $http

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to upload file to ftp after creating new directory in AngularJs using PUT method. when my first request is processing than after sometime I can see duplicate PUT request again when my first request is still uploading file and I get error of Directory already exists.

```
PUT user/audio/deliverftp1  // First request
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1572528
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1637949
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1703388
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1768865
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1834167
PUT user/audio/deliverftp1 - - ms - -   
               // as soon as this line execute I get ERROR
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1899552
```

Here is my partial code for that

```
sync.map(req.body.tracks, function(track, callback) {
    var data = '';
    var filename = '';
    var readableAudioStream = fs.createReadStream(track.trackpath.track_path);
    c.put(readableAudioStream,track.filename, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      callback(null);
    });
    readableAudioStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
      console.log('uploaded Audio >>'+track.track_no+' >>'+data.length);
    });
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log('audio error');
  console.log(err);
  done(err);
});
```

Angular Controller :

```
  $scope.deliverAudio =  function(){
        var ftp1  = albumpackages.delivertoFpt1($rootScope.audio);
        var ftp2  = albumpackages.delivertoFtp2($rootScope.audio);
                Q.allSettled([ftp1,ftp2])
                .then(function (results) {
                    results.forEach(function (result) {
                                console.log('inside result');
                                console.log(result);
                        if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
                            var value = result.value;
                        } else {
                            var reason = result.reason;
                        }
                    });
                });
      }
```

Angular Service:

```
angular.module('albumpackages').factory('albumpackages', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        return{
            delivertoFtp1 : function(audio){
                return $http.put('user/audio/deliverftp1',audio);
            },
            delivertoFtp2 : function(audio){
                return $http.put('user/audio/deliverftp2',audio);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Where is the Angular code making the requests

Comment: Something still isn't right. Your server logs `/user/album/deliverAudio` and the Angular code `PUT`s to `user/audio/deliverftp1` and `user/audio/deliverftp2`.

Comment: now please check, actually I have put partial code for readability.